# When using Spring, call local method directly or use API

Tags: java, spring

Just started learning how to use Spring! As a best practice if you are working on a spring method and you need to add/leverage a piece of functionality that you've already built out in another Spring Class which is accessible via the API, should you use the established API or call it directly?

Comment: What do you mean "use the established API or call it directly"?

Comment: So for example if I am creating a "Office" class and i want to add a couple employees by default whenever i create a new "Office" i've already created the "employee" class and a method to create employees and it's accessible via a mapped url i.e. "/employee/add". Should i locally call that url to add each employee or call the underlying class and method directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a `CustomerService` component

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {
  public Customer getCustomerById(CustomerId id) {
      //your code here
  }
}
```

Suppose now that you have an `OrderService` that needs to find the customer before placing an new order. You definitively would prefer to find the customer using your existing `CustomerService` API.

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

   @Autowire private CustomerService customerService;

   public void placeOrder(Order order, CustomerId custId) {
      Customer customer = customerServive.getCustomerById(custId);
      //your code here
   }
}
```

That totally make sense.

Now suppose you have a controller to expose your `CustomerService` to your web clients.

```
@RestController
public CustomerController {

   @Autowire private CustomerService customerService;   

   @GET("/customer/{custId}")
   public Customer getCustomer(@Param CustomerId custId){
      return customerService.getCustomerById(custId);
   }

}
```

From you `OrderServer` you definitely *don't need to/should not* make an HTTP remote call to this HTTP service to get a customer. That would not make sense if they are both colocated in the JVM. It is a hell of a lot simpler and safer to just use your local service.

If however your `CustomerService` runs in a different process/JVM, one entirely different than the one it runs your `OrderService` than it would make sense to make a remote HTTP call to get your customer.

In a case like this, you probably would have a `CustomerServiceGateway` to make the remote call.

For example, in the orders api

```
interface CustomerService {
   Order getCustomerById(CustomerId custId);
}
```

And then a gateway implementation:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceGateway implements CustomerService {

  @Autowire private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  Order getCustomerById(CustomerId custId) {
     return restTemplate.getForObject("http://customer-api/customer/{custId}", custId);
  }
}
```

This is an oversimplification, but even so you can see that is much harder to do and it only make sense if you try to invoke remote services.

Comment: That's what i thought just making sure there wasn't some reason i wasn't thinking of before i did my entire service setup like that. Thanks!